# How to abandon one 3way switch and convert the other end of the line switch to put in a smart dimmer?

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I am a fairly savvy DIY and am perplexed on how to proceed. I want to remove one 3 way switch with a red, white, black and ground. I am assuming the white is a neutral, but does not appear to be part of my bundled neutrals in the back of the box. When I tie my red and black together and cap off my neutral, then install my new switch at the end of the line box, my new switch does not work. How do I remedy this? In the box I want to keep, I do have a red, black, white as well along with a ground.

First photo, the switch I want to remove, bundled neutrals in back right of box.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGDVY.jpg)

Second pic, box I want to retain, currently connected to a Lutron Diva Dimmer, no bundled neutrals. 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrZuM.jpg)

First switch with better lighting.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulEnr.jpg)

First box again with incoming Romex(https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6IIJ.jpg)

Wiring of switch I want to nix (https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYZAR.jpg)

Other side of switch wiring (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhCO9.jpg)

Comment: There are some code requirements  on the number of switches needed in a room, on stairs, etc.,  are you sure you can remove one of the three way's?  Can you provide pictures of the two switch boxes?

Comment: To keep functionality and maybe also to be code compliant, use a 3-way dimmer. I didn't even know that they existed until my new house had one already installed.

Comment: What make and model of smart switch do you have, and is taking it back and getting a different one an option? Can you post photos of the insides of the switch boxes involved please, for that matter?

Comment: If the white goes to the switch, it is *not* neutral.  Are any other cables in the box?  A cable is several wires together in a common sheath. Describe if you can the cables in the boxes, not just the wires going to the switches.

Comment: There are a few ways the cables for 3-ways can be routed, and sometimes the wrong colored wires get used, so to clearly answer your question we need to know how many 3 conductor and 2 conductor cables are in each switch box, and which colored wires are attached to which colored screws. Pictures work well for that.

Comment: The switch I am trying to install is a gosund smart dimmer, installed one in my kitchen last week, no problem. It’s the elimination of the 3 way that’s creating my headache.

Comment: Excellent  Newbie Post.

Comment: Is taking the Gosund back and getting a better smart dimmer that supports multi-way operation an option?

Comment: I am not aware of any three way dimmers that don’t require a hub, which I have no interest in adding. The gosund is working great in my kitchen and until I am absolutely  sure I don’t have a neutral, I’m not abandoning ship. Forgot to mention I am a tenacious Girlie Girl DIYer. Can’t even begin to tell you how many projects I have done without giving up.

Comment: Jack, this is in a bedroom and the switch I want to remove is actually behind a chest and not used, but is causing me a huge headache right now.

Comment: @GirlieGirlDIYer I know offhand that Leviton makes stuff that can do multi-way "smart" dimming without a hub, just as one example.  Is that switch you want to remove near an entrance to the room, or just off somewhere else, by the way? (Just because a switch is behind furniture doesn't mean that it's not a Code requirement to have a switch there!)

Comment: @ThreePaseEel  the switch I am trying to nix is in the middle of the wall coming out of the master bath, not next to the door frame as would be expected for a code requirement. This is a 1939 house that was added on to in the 90’s. The part I am working on is in the newer section. I appreciate the info regarding Leviton, but I still can’t seem to get an answer to my original question. Does anyone have any advice?